# Having trouble creating subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have a primary query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(population_count),
  age
FROM educational_attainment
GROUP BY age;
```

this gives me total populations of age groups.

The second query is:

```
SELECT
  EducationalAttainment,
  age,
  SUM(population_count) 
FROM educational_attainment
GROUP BY EducationalAttainment, age;
```

This give me sub-populations of age groups with their educational attainments.

So if total population with age group from 18 to 65 is 2 million from first query and I get 34000 same age group from second query.

How can I combined both queries to calculate fraction of 34,000 out of 2,000,000. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For reference:

- [SELECT SYNTAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)
- [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)
- [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)

---

```
SELECT
  by_attainment.EducationalAttainment AS education_attainment,
  by_attainment.age AS age,
  (by_attainment.population_sum/total.population_sum*100) AS percentage,
  total.population_sum AS total_population_sum,
  by_attainment.population_sum AS by_attainment_population_sum
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(population_count) AS population_sum,
    age
  FROM educational_attainment
  GROUP BY age
) AS total,
(
  SELECT
    EducationalAttainment,
    age,
    SUM(population_count) AS population_sum
  FROM educational_attainment
  GROUP BY EducationalAttainment, age
) AS by_attainment
WHERE total.age = by_attainment.age;
```

Results using [test data on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRbUc5gky6SnajsB4pZQYD/18):

```
+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------+
|        education_attainment         |    age    | percentage | total_population_sum | by_attainment_population_sum |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------+
| Bachelor's degree or higher         | 00 to 17  |     0.1499 |              9787619 |                        14673 |
| Bachelor's degree or higher         | 18 to 64  |    30.3232 |            151806895 |                     46032757 |
| Bachelor's degree or higher         | 65 to 80+ |    29.7863 |             28772453 |                      8570246 |
| High school or equivalent           | 00 to 17  |     1.1737 |              9787619 |                       114881 |
| High school or equivalent           | 18 to 64  |    23.4361 |            151806895 |                     35577621 |
| High school or equivalent           | 65 to 80+ |    25.1992 |             28772453 |                      7250424 |
| No high school diploma              | 00 to 17  |    97.7411 |              9787619 |                      9566523 |
| No high school diploma              | 18 to 64  |     16.701 |            151806895 |                     25353234 |
| No high school diploma              | 65 to 80+ |    19.9813 |             28772453 |                      5749114 |
| Some college, less than 4-yr degree | 00 to 17  |     0.9353 |              9787619 |                        91542 |
| Some college, less than 4-yr degree | 18 to 64  |    29.5397 |            151806895 |                     44843283 |
| Some college, less than 4-yr degree | 65 to 80+ |    25.0332 |             28772453 |                      7202669 |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck you made one soul happy, very happy!!

Comment: I found your [other question (not sure why you asked it twice and split useful information between the two)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787294/unable-to-create-a-sub-query). I'm updating the results using the test data provided in the other question.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for taking the time to help

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question. Trying to convey a new question via comments is suboptimal. Or, if it's directly related to the current question, update the question itself.

Comment: I guess you're ignoring what I said above. I don't know the overall schema you're dealing with so I can't help you with the next step. Also, judging from [yet another duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786314/mysql-subquery-confusion-about-calculating-fraction-of-a-sub-population), it looks like this is homework. I think the answer above along with the pointers to the relevant documentation, should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Also worth reading: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (to help get traction with the questions you ask) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (to properly respond when you get useful answers).